# Sublime colour syntax highlighting using regex

Tags: regex, syntax, sublimetext2

I've managed to put together a syntax (.tmLanguage) file for use in Sublime Text 2. I'd quite like to highlight numerals. I tried:

```
<string>0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9</string>
```

which works, but only for single digits, so I thought the regex would be

```
<string>[0-9]</string>
```

But that doesn't work. Can someone please help me with the correct syntax in Sublime?

Comment: What does *"doesn't work"* mean? Did you try `[0-9]+` or `\d+`?

Comment: To explain on @LucasTrzesniewski answer, adding a + after any character matches one OR MORE of the character it's after. In your case, at least one digit, but as many as possible.

Might I suggest `<string>\d+(\.\d+)?</string>` as that will find decimal numbers as well.

Comment: I tried it at the end of an existing string section and oddly only a few numbers changed colours. I just tried it at the start, before the keywords, and it works! `[0-9]+|\b(keyword|anotherkeyword)\b`

Comment: @Mowday go ahaead and put your comment as the answer. I overlooked decimal notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code to:

```
<string>\d+</string>
```

It should find all integers.

- **\d** equals any number (0-9)
- **+** Is a multiplier stating "one or more of the previous character"

In your case, at least one digit, but as many as possible. Might I suggest:

```
<string>\d+(\.\d+)?</string>
```

as that will find decimal numbers as well.

- **\d** equals any number (0-9)
- **+** Is a multiplier stating "one or more of the previous character"
- **(** Starts a group
- **\.** An escaped period sign, to actually capture the period character
- **\d+** One or more digits
- **)** End f the group
- **?** Makes the entire group optional.

That should capture both integers and decimal numbers.